# Removing notification after click

Tags: android

I just started working with notifications and now I'm trying to remove the notification and launch the app once the notification has been tapped in the notificationcenter.

I tried to work with the following code:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;

public class ExpandNotification {
     private int NOTIFICATION = 546;
     private NotificationManager mNM;

     public void onCreate() {
        mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "stopped service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I think this code executes the other class when tapped?

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(this, ExpandNotification.class), 0);
```

However the notification doesn't go away, nor does the application launch.
But I'm able to swipe it to left or right to remove it but that's not what I want..

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the flag `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, pendingIntent);

// Cancel the notification after its selected
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

and to launch the app:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// Create a new intent which will be fired if you click on the notification
Intent intent = new Intent(context, App.class);

// Attach the intent to a pending intent
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, intent_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: What about the situation when you do not specify ContentIntent (just want notification to be removed when tapped)? In this case auto_cancel flag does not seem to help...

Comment: Answering my own comment: you can not do this. The only way to achieve something similar is to create "empty" PendingIntent `.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, ` __new Intent()__ `, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));`  However tapping notification will also hide the notification panel (you will have to bring it back down if you have lots of notifications you need to clear this way).

Comment: What if you are using NotificationCompat.Builder to build your notification?

Answer (score 122):

To get the same effect using `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder` call `setAutoCancel(true)` on the Builder instance.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is too much late but specially i write following solution because notification constructor become deprecated so use notification using builder , like following :

```
 **.setAutoCancel(true)** is used to remove notification on click
```

and entire notification is like follwoing :

```
  private void makeNotification(String title,String msg){

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MasterActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(msg);

    int mNotificationId = 001;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Calling this method with title and message you get perfect notification.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly add `.setAutoCancel(true)` this line into your code in order to remove notification on click.

This must be added in your builder variable.

Example:

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification")
        .setContentText("Hello")
        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Best & simple way is set `builder.setAutoCancel(true)` it's cancel your notification after clicking on notification. I hope this code help you.

Builder for notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star);
builder.setContentTitle("This is title of notification");
builder.setContentText("This is a notification Text");
builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
```

For open an activity on clicking notification

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Broadcastdemo.this, ThreadDemo.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 113,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Show bulder in notification

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(114, builder.build());
```

Complete code for show a notification with icon, image, title, description, auto cancel and on click open an activity

```
public void ShowIntentNotification(View v)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star);
        builder.setContentTitle("This is title of notification");
        builder.setContentText("This is a notification Text");
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Broadcastdemo.this, ThreadDemo.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 113,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(114, builder.build());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For my it was that

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

that was causing the notification to not clear after click... make sure you use:

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

And `.setAutoCancel(true)` should work.