# How hide notification when button clicked?

Tags: java, android

I want to hide my notification when I clicked a button yes or no. My code is working good, but when I clicked a button it goes to home screen. I want to only hide notification without going to home screen. Can you tell me what is the easiest way to make it? Thanks for any advice :)

---

**NotificationReceiver class:**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, RepeatingActivity.class);
        repeating_intent.putExtra("what", 0);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent yes = new Intent(context, RepeatingActivity.class);
        yes.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        yes.putExtra("what", 1);
        PendingIntent yesIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, yes, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent no = new Intent(context, RepeatingActivity.class);
        no.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        no.putExtra("what", 2);
        PendingIntent noIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, no, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle("Hello")
                .setContentText("XD")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.yes, "Yes", yesIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.no, "No", noIntent);

        builder.getNotification().flags |= NotificationCompat.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

---

**RepeatingActivity class:**

```
public class RepeatingActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int what = getIntent().getIntExtra("what",-1);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(0);

        if(what==0) {
            setContentView(R.layout.repeating_activity_layout);
        }
        else if(what==1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Yes!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            goHome();
        }
        else if(what==2) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello No!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            goHome();
        }
    }

    public void goHome() {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `notificationManager.notify(int noficationId, Notification notification)` you pass notificationId as argument. In your case 0. Then call `notificationManager.cancel(int notificationId)`, in your case `notificationManager.cancel(0)` to cancel notification.

Comment: It isn't a problem. I forget to change it in code before adding there :)

Comment: @gianlucas.tukker I am not sure what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag **Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL**

[Removing notification after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972868/removing-notification-after-click)

Comment: "builder.getNotification().flags |= NotificationCompat.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;"

Answer (score 0):

When you build `Notification` with `NotificationCompat.Builder` you should set this `builder.setAutoCancel(true);`

Comment: ".setAutoCancel(true)"

Answer (score 0):

According to [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#Removing)

There are five ways to remove notifications, if you want to remove it by click a button, could do like this:

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();//place this line in click listener of a button
```